# How can I troubleshoot why TinyMCE won't load custom plugins in the visual editor?

Tags: tinymce

**Edit:** Found that the theme options panel set up (using a class) was causing the problem. Still not sure why - would still love know how to find out what the problem is - e.g. is it a JS or PHP issue. Going to try a different method of creating the theme options panel to see if it fixes the problem.

---

I am able to add extra TinyMCE buttons that are bundled (e.g. HR, anchor), but am unable to add custom plugins of my own. I have also noticed that other plugins (WP-Table Reloaded, cForms, TinyMCE Advanced) are also unable to load custom plugins. Disabling all other plugins does not solve the issue. What could be causing this, and/or how can I find the problem?

When viewing source of an edit post screen, mceInit options do not list any plugins besides those defined as WP default. Altering the $initArray does work, but of course does not point to the correct location of added plugins.

Comment: I've never experienced this problem, with or without TinyMCE Advanced. Paste your code.

Comment: What code, exactly? I actually only started attempting to add plugins myself because TinyMCE Advanced was not showing buttons that require a plugin, so I took the functionality of TinyMCE Advanced and put it directly in my theme's functions.php file to learn and see if the problem was the plugin. I then noticed that I wasn't seeing buttons from other plugins, either. WP plugins seem to work just fine (more/next, kitchen sink).

Comment: I posted a link to the codex article on this topic. That should be able to answer most of your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read this: http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Buttons

It's pretty straightforward if you already know how to program a TinyMCE plugin (which it sounds like you do).

Comment: Well unfortunately this doesn't explain why plugins with TinyMCE integration that work in other installations aren't working, either. Still trying to find how I can troubleshoot what is going wrong.

Comment: Then you need to post the code you're working with. Asking for help troubleshooting an issue like this with no code doesn't give us anything useful to go off of.

Comment: Like I stated, I only started attempting to add custom TinyMCE plugins because I noticed that TinyMCE Advanced was not adding certain buttons, so "my" code started as a direct copy of that plugin. It was then that I realized that there were other active plugins that should be adding TinyMCE buttons that were not appearing (also noted above), so it appears to be a problem universal to this WP installation, not specific to my code. I can certainly copy-paste the code if you'd like. I'm trying to figure out what could be going wrong that would cause this kind of behavior.